# подключил файл через кастомную функцию подключения но php вовыводит что переменная не найденна

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

здраствуйте я пытаясь вывести пост из db
в подключаемом файле через кастомную функцию, но
php не может найти переменную я пробывал использовать просто функцию require и все работает корретно. обьясните почему php не видит переменную
через мою кастомную функцию?

вот место подключения

```
<?php require('functions.php'); 

if(isset($_GET['href']))
{
  reqdb('mysql','127.0.0.1','myblog','root','toor'); 
  $project =     R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM projects WHERE `href` = ?', array($_GET['href']) ); 
  if(empty($project))
  {
    die;
  }
  $project = array_shift($project);
?>

<?php get_header() ?>
        <div class="main__box project-item ">
            <?php   get_content('project.php'); // здесь  ?>
        </div>
<?php   get_footer(); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

вот сама кастомная функция

```
function get_content($filename )
{
  $filename = 'content/' . $filename;
  if(file_exists($filename))
  {
     require_once($filename);
  }
  else
  {
     die($filename . " does`t exist please check filename");
  }
}
```

в project.php просто вывод переменной

```
<?php print_r($project);die; ?>
```

Comment: версия php 7.3.7

Comment: файл project.php будет видеть только те переменные, которые есть в теле функции `get_content()`, или глобальные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя загрузка проходит во функций, а там переменную не видит. Вот документация по проблеме https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115215/discussion-on-answer-by-sdarkness------).